# Hosted site sets Material Design Icons opacity to 1% (localhost is 40%)

Tags: html, css, iis

So I have a hosted web project on our domain IIS. In our project we use installed Material Design Icons. My problem: I have a disabled icon css class that sets the opacity of that item to 40%, this works perfectly locally, but hosted it sets it to 1% for some unknown reason.

Can someone explain me why and how to fix it please?

Comment: From the sound of it local uses a different CSS than hosted. Did you upload your changes? (and reloaded the page in your browser [Ctrl-F5]?) Otherwise: [reprex]. SO is not a guessing site...

Comment: The CSS file setting it to 1% is overriding the one that sets it to 40%. Either rearrange the position in which they are loaded or overwrite it with "on page" CSS.

Comment: Ok. Then it is possible the 1% CSS contains rules with the `!important` attribute added to them.

Comment: I understand but I don't have a 1% css anywhere. This is the only piece of code that handles the opacity anywhere: .disabledButton{
    opacity: 40%!important;
}

Comment: try using **0.4** instead of **40%** as opacity accepts values between 0 and 1 [w3school: opacity](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)

Comment: Setting it to 0.4 did the job! Thanks alot!